# Uninstall Ubuntu and bring back Windows 7

Tags: 12.10, windows, uninstall

I accidently installed Ubuntu 12.10 using the option "LVM" although i've not selected erase disk and fresh install. Now my systems boots direclt into Ubuntu and I'm unable to see my Windows files on hard drive so I'm unable to access my old data (documents, movies, music, pictures) stored on Windows? Can someone help me to bring back my old Windows?

In fact, I've now completely erased my hard drive yesterday and its only ubuntu 12.10 running on my laptop and i surely want to install my paid windows 7 home premium back as a dual booting system.
But I also like to first try uninstall or revert my ubuntu installations and get back my windows so that i'll able to at least retrieve my previous data and than perform this new task.

Comment: You're asking how to uninstall Ubuntu and revert to Windows, which is completely understandable given your current situation, but did you know that it's possible to have both Windows and Ubuntu live side-by-side on your computer, and still be able to boot into both whenever you want? Would you like us to tell you how to do that or would you still prefer to remove Ubuntu?

Comment: Yeah sure chris, please go ahead and guide, infact i've now completely erased my hard drive yesterday and its only ubuntu 12.10 running on my laptop and i surely want to install my paid windows 7 home prem. back as a dual booting system.

Comment: @ Chris, but i also like to first try uninstall or revert my ubuntu installations and get back my windows so that i'll able to at least retrieve my previous data and than perform this new task.

Comment: You say "infact i've now completely erased my hard drive yesterday and its only ubuntu 12.10 running on my laptop". Are you saying you've removed Windows? If so, then your data might be quite tricky to get back.

Answer (score -1):

Easiest way would be to try the Recovery disk for windows 7. It has repair option to repair the boot management. It should automatically detect your windows and fix its Boot issue. ( you will loose Ubuntu boot option with it)

Second option is to Prepare a USB stick with Ubuntu in it. Re-install the whole thing from Scratch and leave windows 7 partition as it is.

It will give you both Ubuntu and Windows 7. :)

Comment: Nope, he/she wiped his/her hard-drive

Answer (score -1):

Then why did you erase your hard-drive?! If you erase your hard-drive, your data is gone! That's too obvious!

Also, why don't you have a backup?!

Stop using your computer NOW. You might be able to rescue your data!

Every time you write data to your hard-drive, the chance of possibility you might be able to rescue your data lowers! So stop using your computer NOW!

Create an [Ubuntu Rescue Remix](http://ubuntu-rescue-remix.org/Version12-04) disk, boot from it and rescue your data using these instructions: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DataRecovery#Lost_Partition

---

Also, you don't have to delete Ubuntu in order to use Windows. You can have Windows alongside Ubuntu. The installer asked that.